# Adding Admob and Google Play Game Services ANE to flash as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, ane

I am trying to add Google Play Game Service ANE and Admob ANE to the same project and I keep getting the error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name cacheInterstitial.
at flash.external::ExtensionContext/_call()
at flash.external::ExtensionContext/call()
at com.pozirk.ads.admob::AdMob/cacheInterstitial()[D:\Pozirk\_projects\ANEAdMob\air\AdMob\com\pozirk\ads\admob\AdMob.as:83]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
at runtime::AppRunner/run()
at ADLAppEntry/run()
at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
Cannot display source code at this location.
```

Here is what my code looks like, Im not sure what I am doing wrong, if someone could help me I would be very grateful:

```
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.*
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirGooglePlayGames.*

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var admob:AdMob = new AdMob();
    private var googlePlayGames:AirGooglePlayGames = new AirGooglePlayGames()

    public function Main()
    {       
        googlePlayGames.startAtLaunch();
        // Show Leaderboard
        googlePlayGames.showLeaderboard("000000000000000000");
        admob.init();
        admob.cacheInterstitial("ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000");
        admob.cacheInterstitial("ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000");
```

And here is my XML Descriptor file:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
  <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
               <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
<!-- GooglePlay Games Services -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ 90007276375" />
<activity android:name="com.freshplanet.googleplaygames.SignInActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
</manifest>]]>
</manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Comment: First thing where is your extensions tag in xml? Follow all the required steps given by ane developer.

Comment: Oops sorry, I have the extension tag, I just forgot to include it in this post @sameerjain